# How to delete image from Parse?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform

I want to delete / overwrite a photo to Parse for a given user. Will you help me? Because I wrote the code that I always return error 102

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"User"];

[query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];

[query includeKey:@"Foto"];

[query whereKeyExists:@"Dev.png"];   //Change this condition to fetch the row.

[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object1, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error) {
         NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved: %@", object1);

         //This might work as I searched for this deleting image but there is no method to do so.
         //So a way would be is to get that object and then setting nil value in it's place.
         //Else if u want to delete the entire row then u could simply type, [object deleteInBackground]
         object1[@"Foto"] = [NSNull null];
     }
     else
     {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
     }
 }];
```

This is my table:

[image: http://cl.ly/YKCa]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
[query whereKey:@"User" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```

With below line:

```
[query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
```